# @Html.JQueryUI() - Does not contain a definition for JQueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I'm sure this is something simple I just can't find it.

In any view that I try and use @Html.JQueryUI().something I'm getting a compile error telling me that JQueryUI does not contain a definition for JQueryUI, and no extension method of type JQueryUI excepts a first argument of type System.Web.MVC.HtmlHelper. I'm asked if I'm missing an assembly reference or using statement.

I have verified that all the required js and css files are being loaded to the page when it is rendered to the browser by looking at the page source, and clicking each of the file links which return the correct file.

In this MVC 4 project I'm using the BundleConfig class to include all css/js files which are these:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/trontastic/css").Include(
                           "~/Content/themes/trontastic/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                           "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

I'm rendering the scripts/css in my _Layout page

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/trontastic/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

JQuery Validate is only rendered on the create and edit view pages.

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

The line of code that returns this error on .JQueryUI() for any view.

```
@Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("anotherDate").MinDate(DateTime.Today).ShowButtonPanel(true)
```

I have verified that all the required js and css files are being loaded to the page when it is rendered in the browser by looking at the page source and clicking each of the file links.

Comment: Where is your HtmlHelper extension of @Html.JQueryUI()? Never heard about this one, do you have your own implementation?

Comment: Are you using this one: http://jqueryuihelpers.apphb.com/Docmo/GettingStarted?

Comment: Thanks for responding Simon... Yes I did use this jqueryuihelpers link as a test by trying to add a date picker to see if I wired up the theme I create form JQuery correctly. My main goal is to use this theme for the entire site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the namespace for JQueryUI HtmlHelper in the webconfig. Open file `~/Views/Web.config` and add:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
       <namespaces>
           <add namespace="JQueryUIHelpers" />
       </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

**EDIT**

Sometimes you have to close your views or even visual studio to adapt new namespaces in the weg.config

**EDIT 2**

I just installed this package via nuget. The namespace is added automatically but no so the dll reference. Have a look at your references and add reference for `JQueryUIHelpers.dll` and rebuild your project. Worked for me.

Comment: I added the example code you provided to the root webconfig file saved and closed VS. Now every @Html statement in every view for the project has the save error.

Comment: I hope you didn't include the whole snippet. You only had to add the line `<add namespace="JQueryUIHelpers" />` **if it's not already in there!!**

Comment: I added the reference to JQueryUIHelpers through NuGet, and removed the snipped you provided then added only the namespace <add namespace="JQueryUIHelpers" />. This has corrected the problem I was having with the missing reference. It's odd that no post/google search I found had any instructions on adding this a namespace, or the JQueryUIHelpers as a reference. In any case thanks for your help Simon this fixed my issue!

Answer (score 1):

I'd also recommend to upgrade to .net framework 4.5.1 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/5a4x27ek(v=vs.110).aspx) JQueryUIHelpers didn't work for me until I installed the new version and changed the project application properties to use 4.5.1.

Comment: This solved the problem for me.  I simply changed the framework version to 4.5.1 and all is well!

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same problem...

I already had .Net 4.5.1 installed, the web.config was already correct and the dll was already added.

I had to add:

```
@using JQueryUIHelpers;
```